# MySQL - Good way of storing small arrays in field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a small app in 5 languages and I made homepage's banners managing.

My question is how to store in which language each banner shows? I think that creating next tables just too much, so i've done it this way:

I have field languages and i save there data like this: "[en][de][fr]"

I am looking for each language with this query: "LIKE '%[en]%'"
I am serializing it and unserializing it using my php functions.

Is there any more efficient/correct way to store this information without using another table?

Comment: You could use a `SET`.

Comment: The best way is to create another table, truly.  Creating a table is easy, you do it once, and then your data is tidy and easy to get to, and, particularly, query.

Comment: Using `"LIKE '%[en]%'"` means indexes are useless, so any growth in the data will lead to performance slowdowns... and you'll run into a myriad of other problems in due course with extra codework needed to add/modify/delete.... and all because you think that creating a new table is too much..... believe me, it isn't too much, as the thousands of questions posted here every month by people like yourself who think it was too much attest

Comment: So now if i have another table how would look searching for it? When i have one banner in 3 languages. First i search for needed languages and then join? How to get rid of repeating rows? Use distinct on banner_id?

Comment: `SET` is MySQL column type which could have several of pre-defined values. It consumes only 1 byte (for up to 255 values) and can easily use indexes - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a separate table, it's not too much, it will be faster, cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: So now if i have another table how would look searching for it? When i have one banner in 3 languages. First i search for needed languages and then join? How to get rid of repeating rows? Use distinct on banner_id?